# image in line with text

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell which has both text and an image icon in it. The image icon takes up the height of the cell, which makes the text drop to the bottom:
[image]

Now, I want the text to position itself in the middle of the cell:
[image]

Pray, how might I achieve this? The usual padding and margin fixes don't seem to work. My code is as follows:

```
<td class="title">
     <div style="display:inline-block;">Blah blah</div> 
      <a href="#"><img src="img.png" width="68" height="34" alt="Imange"></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to make your `line-height` the height of the image, then use `vertical-align` to adjust where the text lies vertically:

```
.title {
    line-height: 34px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add vertical-align:middle as a style to your img tag, like so:

```
<td class="title">
 <div style="display:inline-block;">Blah blah</div> 
  <a href="#"><img src="img.png" width="68" height="34" alt="Imange" style="vertical-align:middle;"></a>
```